# Load different images based on text label in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a `Table View` with basic label of `Table View Cell`. I labelled the cell as "January", "February", "March", etc. When user tap on "January", an image with file name "jan.jpeg" will be showed using the following Swift code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage(named: "jan.jpeg")!
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), size:image.size)
}
```

My question is, is it possible when user tap on "February", "feb.jpeg" will be showed, whereas "mar.jpeg will be showed if user tap on "Mar"? How to implement this?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible, and note really hard to do - where is your above code written? How is your tableview filled with values, how does your prepareForSegue look like?

Comment: ya you can do it ...  create the one transparent view and place the one image view and add the close button . when user tap the cell show the image when user tap the close button hidden the view  thats all ....

Comment: @luk2302, I'm using storyboard to link "January" to `UIScrollView` which shows the image. The tableview is pre-filled manually using storyboard as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a cell is selected, the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method is called. If you have a predefined list of cells, you can test which cell is being tapped and load the correct image.  For example:

have a variable `var imgName: String` outside of all functions in the viewcontroller with your tableView.

Also put this function in the viewcontroller with your tableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        imgName = "jan.jpeg"
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        imgName = "feb.jpeg"
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        imgName = "mar.jpeg"
    }
    else {
        // Handle else
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImageSegue", sender: self)
}
```

You will need to go to interface builder and name the segue between your viewcontrollers to "showImageSegue".

Additionally, implement the `prepareForSegue:` function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as ImageViewController // Replace ImageViewController with whatever the name of your destination viewcontroller is.
    destinationVC.imageName = imgName
}
```

Finally, inside the `ImageViewController` class, add this:

```
var imageName: String
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0,0, 0,0), size: image.size)
}
```

Comment: But currently my code is under `func viewDidLoad()`. How to move it to `func tableView`?

Comment: @user2872856 You will have to create the func tableView and put the code into it as I have shown.

Comment: Sorry, I am a self learner and my knowledge is limited. Appreciate if you can tell me what modification I should made to `func viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Sorry I might be misunderstanding, are you trying to open the image in a new viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, the image will be open in a new viewcontroller.

Comment: @user2872856 I edited my answer.  Hopefully this is helpful.